# enable and disable checkbox column in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a checkbox column. Then there is this button which has been disabled at *formInitialization*. Now, I want to enable it only and only when one of the checkboxes is selected. I have succeeded, partially. This is the code.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (dgvr.Cells[2].Value != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)(dgvr.Cells[2].Value) == true)
                    {
                        button3.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button3.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

However, it only works if there are two or more checked checkboxes, because the first time *cellClick* event is fired, it checks if any of the checkboxes are selected, which they are not. Thus, the button is not enabled. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this piece of code does what I intend it to do. This piece of code DOES check initial and final states.

```
private void dataGridView2_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView2.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                dataGridView2.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }
```